# Cordova app not hitting API on Android - net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: android, cordova, ember.js, content-security-policy

I've looked through a lot of similar issues, but none have seemed to work for me. Our app makes 2 API requests - the first to fetch an OAuth code to our API (works fine) and the other posts that code to the Rails API (which is failing).

I am posting to `http://localhost:3000/api/v1/users/auth/openid_connect/callback`

But getting `net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`. However, this works fine when running on iOS.

My config currently has:

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1" />
<access origin="*" />
<allow-navigation href="*" />
<allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
```

I've tried adding `<allow-intent href="http://localhost:3000/api/v1/*" />` and `<allow-intent href="http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/v1/*" />` and even the full `openid_connect/callback` URL but none seem to work.

In my `index.html`, I have

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *; connect-src * 'unsafe-inline'">
```

Does the issue lie with how I am handling `access origin` in the config or do I have the `Content-Security-Policy` wrong?

Comment: are you using mobile data for testing?is it working over wifi?

Comment: I'm running through an emulator and using the same API/data as my web app (from my Rails/Postgres app)

Comment: Is it possible that you have a proxy set up that goes through to your backend? This, of course, wouldn't work on a device where that proxy isn't set up.

That's how Ionic does it, excuse me if this is senseless.

Comment: @sbatson could be a possible proxy issue if it dont work only in device, that's why I raised de question

Comment: Found this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27119227/cordova-angular-get-to-web-api-connection-refused

Changing it from `localhost:3000` to `10.0.2.2:3000` seemed to fix. Will have to force Android to make requests through that domain in development.

Comment: Changing the domain name like localhost to IP address, solved my problem so you got to change domain in server like nodejs like :   app.listen(3000,'192.168.0.103');
 and use the IP address in ajax call to the API.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To close the issue, the error was that Android didn't seem to know how to handle `localhost`. Changing the domain to `http://10.0.2.2` solved the problem.

Comment: where I have to change this domain,im new to Cordova app development

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58317857/failed-to-load-resource-neterr-connection-refused-cordova-android    , kindly give a solution to this question